# Rails Config: Passing ENV vars to ngrok.yml for use in Procfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml, config, foreman, ngrok

In Rails 4.2.6 I have a `Procfile.dev` that is used with [Foreman](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman)

```
web: bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
.
tunnel: ./ngrok start subdomain -config config/ngrok.yml
.
```

I try and pass through my ENV variables into the `config/ngrok.yml` file:

```
authtoken: <%= ENV['NGROK_AUTHTOKEN'] %>
  tunnels:
    tunnel_1:
      proto: http
      addr: 5000
      subdomain: <%= ENV['NGROK_SUBDOMAIN'] %>
```

[Ngrok](https://ngrok.com/docs) support confirmed that ngrok will not process ERB.

So I tried the following:

Add `config/initializers/ngrok.rb`:

```
NGROK_CONFIG = Rails.application.config_for(:ngrok)
```

Add `config/ngrok.rb`:

```
Rails.application.config_for(:ngrok).to_yaml
```

Run the following in my `Procfile.dev`

```
tunnel: ./ngrok start milner -config config/ngrok.rb
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  Failed to read configuration: Error reading configuration file     
'config/ngrok.rb': YAML parsing error: yaml: unmarshal errors:
line 1: cannot unmarshal !!str `Rails.a...` into main.Config
```

My fallback was to pass the ENV var through the `Profile.dev` as follows:

```
tunnel: ./ngrok http -subdomain=$NGROK_SUBDOMAIN 5000
```

However, **I need to run a more complex ngrok config and would like to take advantage of the ngrok.yml config.**

I'm not sure where to go from here.